does not see the aoigram library in VS Cod, what should I do?
I wrote the telegram bot code. When running the main file, it throws an error:
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'aiogram'
I use VS Code, installed aiogram and before that the code worked, but after editing it stopped.
Here are the code files:
import asyncio
from aiogram import Bot, Dispatcher
from bot_handlers import dp
from database import create_tables

API_TOKEN = '7219879832:AAH2izLkXz1E92R9oFt5W7r5C-Pwn_b-7S0'

async def on_startup(dispatcher):
    await create_tables()

async def main():
    bot = Bot(token=API_TOKEN)
    dp = Dispatcher()
    dp.startup.register(on_startup)
    await dp.start_polling(bot)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    asyncio.run(main())

the point is that I needed to add the output of player statistics, but after the changes, he stopped seeing the aiogram library. I installed it again = it didn't help

did you turn on venv?

how to do it? I've never used it before

have you got a folder in project named venv or env?

yes, I created it, the 'venv' folder appeared

not was asking you to create it. I asked if you already have this folder

initially, it did not exist, I used python -m venv venv

aight, if you further more don't need answer to your question you can do the following: open terminal. be sure that pwd is your project dir.  run venv\Scripts\activate  if you are using WIndows or source ./venv/bin/activate if you are using linux

then install all libs. every time when you enter vscode be sure venv is running

I did as you said, if you run it through the terminal, then the bot simply does not work, if you click run it gives an error:
Failed to fetch updates - TelegramConflictError: Telegram server says - Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running
Sleep for 5.009779 seconds and try again... (tryings = 23, bot id = 7219879832)

you have other bot running with this api-key. MAYBE because you gave your bot api-key here for public

You left your Private Bot Token in your code. You should revoke it ASAP by talking to the @BotFather. People might abuse the token.
